# Вопрос по Vue3 + LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage, vue3

Как вы работаете с LocalStorage в Vue3.

Я сделал метод который создаёт `account_key: value` в локальное хранилище.

```
generateAccountKey () {
    let account_key = localStorage.getItem('account_key');

    if (!account_key) {
        localStorage.setItem('account_key', this.randomString(64));
    }
}
```

Вопрос: могу ли я создать где-то переменную например `account_key = localStorage.getItem('account_key')` и чтобы она была доступна любому компоненту?

Comment: Простой ответ — да. Но зачем вам переменная которая доступна любому компоненту? Вам нужен account_key в любом компоненте? Думаю что скорее всего нет.

Comment: Да это я знал. Я пытался сделать чтобы можно было как то получить отдельную переменную к которой уже присвоено значение ключа из localStorage.

Спасибо за ответ(комментарий).

Comment: Vuex: "я что, для вас какая-то шутка?"))))

Comment: Если проект будет расширятся то буду использовать vuex(у меня не останется другого выбора). И да действительно используя vuex сеттеры/геттеры можно будет решить любую задачу которая связанна с передачей данных куда угодно в рамках приложения.

Большое спасибо за Ваш комментарий.